# PluginPackager tool - Ocean 2017

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am migrating a Petrel plug-in project (using ocean framework) from  Petrel 2015 version to 2017 version. My post-build event uses PluginPackager.exe tool, that is located in Ocean2015Home (..\Schlumberger\Petrel 2015), but it is not located in Ocean2017Home. Is there a new tool to replace PluginPackager? Or is there a new procedure to create pip file? Or is there something wrong with my Petrel 2017 installation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PluginPackager.exe is available with 2017 and is in the Petrel installation directory (OCEAN2017HOME).

A simple approach is to delete the PIP builder project and create a new one.